# Microsoft Azureのweb App のグローバルアドレスを作りたい。

Tags: azure

WebAppにデプロイしたnodejsで作ったアプリから外部のApiを利用するため、利用元にグローバルアドレスを報告しなければならなくなりました。WebAppのグローバルIPアドレスはどのように設定すれば良いでしょうか。またはグローバルIPアドレスを知る方法をご教示いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: ハズしてる気がしますが、Azure＞WebAppのダッシュボード＞左メニュー＞「カスタムドメイン」に記載が無いでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとう。教えていただいた画面にIPアドレスはありましたがこちらがパブリックIPなのでしょうか？確認方法等ありましたらご教示いただけないでしょうか？

Comment: ごめんなさい、確認手段は分からないです。kongou_aeさんの回答がより詳しいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

外部の API から見た WebApps のグローバル IP アドレスを知りたいというご質問だと理解しました。次の URL をご確認ください。

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#when-outbound-ips-change